# Вытащить содержимое тега и записать в сессию

Tags: jquery, javascript

Я не силён в `jQuery` и пытался сделать так: при клике по выбранному тегу `<a>` вытащить его содержимое и записать в сессию, например:
`$_SESSION['my_text_in_teg']`. Всё находится в одном файле.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как, что и куда.
Заранее огромное спасибо.

Comment: Вам поможет ajax.

Comment: Мне просто нужно вытащить из тега текст(по которому я кликнул) в например <div ="to">Сюда</div>

Comment: в обработчике click

   var text=$(this).text();

Comment: Какое уважение? Ты о чём?

Comment: @geer_so, лучший комментарий за сегодня.

Comment: В общем, вот что получилось:

    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#foo').click(function(){
     var text=$(this).text();
 success: function(data){
         $("#block").text(data);
        }

     });
    });

Цель такова: нажимаю сюда <div id="foo">Текст</div>
          и вылазит здесь <div id="block"></div> (между дивами)     
Библиотека работает. Помогите исправить косяк.))

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function call() {
    var c_value = document.getElementById('tutu').getAttribute('name');

        setCookie("TEST", c_value, expires:3600);
    }

function setCookie(name, value, options) {
    options = options || {};
    var expires = options.expires;
    if (typeof expires == "number" && expires) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires*1000);
        expires = options.expires = d;
    }
    if (expires && expires.toUTCString) {
        options.expires = expires.toUTCString();
    }
    value = encodeURIComponent(value);
    var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;
    for(var propName in options) {
        updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
        var propValue = options[propName];   
        if (propValue !== true) {
            updatedCookie += "=" + propValue;
        }
    }
    document.cookie = updatedCookie;
}

</script>

<div id='tutu' name='TEST_COOKIE' onClick='call()'></div>
```

Это всего лишь пример, за работоспособность не ручаюсь.
Но, думаю, главное тут было донести смысл. После выполнения по идее будет кука TEST со значением TEST_COOKIE.

Comment: Кажется, в заголовке и в тэгах jQuery.

Comment: В общем, вот что получилось: 

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#foo').click(function(){
 var text=$(this).text();
 success: function(data){
     $("#block").text(data);
    }

});
});

Цель такова: нажимаю сюда <div id="foo">Текст</div>
          и вылазит здесь <div id="block"></div> (между дивами)     
Библиотека работает. Помогите исправить косяк.))